# How to manage patching on multiple AWS accounts with different schedules

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, patch, aws-opsworks

I'm looking for the best way to manage patching Linux systems across AWS accounts with the following things to consider:

- Separate schedules to roll patches through Dev, QA, Staging and Prod sequentially
- Production patches to be released on approval, not automatic
- No newer patches can be deployed to Production than what was already deployed to lower environments (as new patches come out periodically throughout the month)

We have started by caching all patches in all environments on the first Sunday of every month. The goal there was to then install patches from cache. This helps prevent un-vetted patches being installed in prod.

Most, not all, instances are managed by OpsWorks, but there are numerous OpsWorks stacks. We have some other instances managed by Chef Server. Still others are not managed, but are just simple EC2 instances created from the EC2 console. This means, using recipes means we have to kick off approved patches on a stack-by-stack basis or instance-by-instance basis. Not optimal.

More recently, we have looked at the new features of SSM using a central AWS account to manage instances. However, this causes problems with some applications because the AssumeRole for SSM adds credentials to the .aws/config file that interferes with other tasks we need to run.

We have considered other tools, such as Ansible, but we would like to explore staying within the toolset we currently have which is largely OpsWorks and Chef Server. I'm looking for ideas that are more on a higher level, an architecture of how one would approach this scenario.

Thanks for any thoughts or ideas.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds like one of the exact scenarios RunCommand was designed for.

You can create multiple groups of servers with different schedules based on tags.  More importantly, you don't need to rely on secret/keys being deployed anywhere.

Comment: That's using SSM, correct? I've been working on that and was excited to see the updates where you can register all accounts with a central account's SSM and managed all EC2 instances from a single SSM. The problem is, it seems to automatically add entries to the .aws/config file which causes issues with other applications. It took us a while to figure that out because the IAM role used for the instances should have allowed the access we needed and we didn't realize that it was updating the local keys. We'd remove the keys and they would re-appear 30 minutes later until I deregistered it.

Comment: Where do you see these keys?  Anything running on EC2 should use an instance profile - I have never heard of anything updating .aws/config

Comment: It keeps showing up in /root/.aws/config. If we removed it, it was back in 30 minutes. This stopped happening when I deregistered the instance from SSM. It took a while to figure out because, like you, I assumed the IAM role should be handling everything.

Comment: @DanielCarrington: What OS / AMI are you using?  Who owns the keys that are added?

Comment: It's our own AMI, but based on the 2017.09 AmazonLinux AMI. I'm not sure who owns the keys. I'm not sure how to determine that. I can tell you it's not from a user we generated. It seems to be generated by the SSM agent.

Comment: @DanielCarrington
I am actually looking for the same requirement did you find any solution for this patching routine.

Comment: Not yet. Still looking around. Going to be looking at Foreman, Spacewalk and a few others.